Can Playwright show a message in the browser to a user?
When using Selenium, a message like this would show up in the browser:
Selenium Browser Message

Chrome is being controlled by automated test software.

Using Playwright, I'd like to show a similar message, except I'd like to provide the text/HTML.
Is that possible?  If so, how?
(I'm using C#)
I've googled for different APIs but cant seem to find what I'm looking for.

That’s not possible. That message is shown by the browser not the automation tool.

While it is not possible as mentioned by hardkoded; there may be a walk around. Here is my suggestion, but it is typescript - I believe you can modify it to C#.
test.describe('Javascript Evaulate Method', () => {
    test('I am lucky!', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('https://google.co.uk');

    // walk around to show the message
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        const bar = document.createElement('div');
        bar.textContent = 'Chrome is being controlled by automated test software.';
        bar.style.cssText = 'position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; background: lightgrey; color: black; text-align: left; padding: 8px; font-size: 14px; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; z-index: 9999;';
        document.body.style.paddingTop = '30px';
        document.documentElement.prepend(bar);
    });

    // dummy test
    const luckyButton = await page.locator('input[name="btnI"]');
    await expect(luckyButton).toBeVisible();

    });
});

Basically you would use page.evaluate() method to trigger a javascript code which generate the message bar. You can modify the text and its style. In this demonstration, I used that method in a test block; but you may want to call it from beforeEach etc.
